# How do I make a pipe dynamic angular2

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have the following UI buttons:
[Show All] [Category 1] [Category 2]

I would like to use `filterBy` from `ngx-pipes` (https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes) to filter my data.

`Usage: array | filterBy: [prop, nested.prop, ...]: search: [strict | optional]`

From the docs, their example is: `{{ users | filterBy: ['work.company']: 'Bar Tech' }}`

1. Instead of 'Bar Tech' being a 'hard coded' filter, I would like to assign a variable 'currentCategory' instead - how do I do that? Do I simply replace `Bar Tech` with `currentCategory`?
2. How do I make the pipe update on button click? I understand I can bind a (click) event, however I am not quite sure how to update `currentCategory` though the (click) which would prompt the pipe to filter again.

In other words: Using buttons, I would like to update my displayed data based on a matching property (button's value must be in object's property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st.**: Yes.

**2nd.**: You should import the `pipe` inside your `component` and call `.transform()` on button `(click)` *event*.

```
import { FilterByPipe } from 'ngx-pipes/src/app/pipes/array/filter-by';

@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [FilterByPipe]
})
export class AppComponent {

  filteredArr: any[]; // your correct type   

  constructor(private readonly filterByPipe: FilterByPipe) {
    // ...
    this.filteredArr = this.users.slice(); // clone array by value (not by reference)
  }

  onClickBtn() {
    this.filteredArr = this.filterByPipe.transform(
      this.users, 
      'work.company',
      this.currentCategory
    );
  }
}
```

Remember to change the source array in your `template`, you should use:

```
*ngFor="let <variable> of filteredArr"...
```

Comment: Can you explain `onClickBtn` ? Is it a name you decided on, or.. ?

Comment: It's just a fake name.. you can name it anyway.

Comment: I can pass currentCategory through this function, and bind it to my (click)="" event, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can.. `(click)="YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME(currentCategory)"`.

Comment: this didn't change my display data on click :(

Comment: this is my current constructor: 
`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _EdmundsAPIService: EdmundsAPIService,
              private filterByPipe: FilterByPipe) {}` 

so I don't know how to implement yours