# How to use custom pipes Angular2

Tags: json, angular, angular-pipe

I have the following JSON object: http://pastebin.com/1TguvZXc

Here is my Models Component HTML:

```
<button *ngFor="let category of categories"    (click)="chooseCategory(this.category)" type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-default" id="{{category}}">
  {{category}}
</button>  
<div *ngFor="let model of models?.models">
  <div *ngFor="let year of model['years']">
    <div *ngFor="let style of year['styles'] | chooseCategory">
        {{model.name}}, {{style.submodel.body }}
   </div>
 </div>
```

A (pipe?) method from my models.component:

```
chooseCategory(selectedCategory: string): void {
    if((selectedCategory === '')) {
      this.filterByPipe.transform(this.models,
                     ['models.years.styles.submodel.body'], selectedCategory);
    }
 }
```

Additionally, I would like to use the `FilterByPipe` pipe from `ngx-pipes` to filter out by category in `models.years.styles.submodel.body`.

The code from my HTML roduces the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'chooseCategory' could not be found ("or="let model of models?.models">
  <div *ngFor="let year of model['years']">
    <div *ngFor="let s[ERROR ->]tyle of year['styles'] | chooseCategory">
        {{model.name}}, {{style.submodel.body }}
```

Comment: I've described clearly how to make custom pipes here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42094880/6695924

Comment: @Kinduser, to expand on your post (which I saw and upvoted) - I would appreciate an understanding on how to implement this pipe through a (click) function from buttons

Comment: You want the pipe to execute on button click? Or I didn't understand you correctly?

Comment: @Kinduser, I want the button click to pass an argument (category) to my pipe, and execute it. Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you not even read the documentation. Yu should create pipe in this way:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'somePipe'
})
export class SomePipe {

   transform(value: any[]): any[] {
      //some transform code...
   }
}
```

and then can you call that in HTML file in this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of elements | somePipe"></div>
```

Dont forget to declare your pipe in module.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [ SomePipe ]
})
```

That's what you use is a method, not a pipe.

If you want to executing pipe depend on (f.e.) button click you should build Pipe with argument:

```
   @Pipe({
      name: 'somePipe'
   })
   export class SomePipe {
      transform(value: any[], args: any[]): any[] {
         let someFlag: boolean = false;
         if(args && args[0]) someflag = true;
         if(someflag) {
            //some transform code...
         }
      }
   }
```

to call this pipe in this way

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of elements | somePipe : yesOrNo"></div>
```

and then can you use in your component method to click button

```
yesOrNo: boolean = false;

onClickButton(event: any) {
   event.preventDefault();
   yesOrNo = !yesOrNo;
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Im not sure you understand the concept of pipe. You can use " | " pipe symbol in your HTML code in way presented by me. Or you can call _transform_ method in your TypeScript file. But you can't using pipe symbol on whichever method

Comment: i edit my post to explain how can you use arguments in pipe

Answer (score 1):

Since you're importing the `pipe` and calling it from a button in your `component`, you don't need to call the pipe directly in your `component`. Also, `chooseCategory` is just a `method`, not a `pipe`. Then, remove the `pipe` from the following line:

```
<div *ngFor="let style of year['styles'] | chooseCategory">
```

Comment: how do I make this into a pipe? I need it to filter by categories w/ buttons

Comment: I can't understand what do you want finally ^^. Some minutes ago you asked [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42140805/4911842) question for call `pipe` from a button, now you want the inverse..

Comment: I have a JSON response that is displaying all objects in NgFor="". using buttons, I plan on filtering this models data in the ngFor="" to display all the models that match the 'submodel.body' (category)

Comment: Please, explain how this question is different from that another that you posted some time ago..

Comment: The previous question tried to accomplish accessing the data and filtering for uniqueness (still didn't get the uniqueness quite right). Now I want to expand on that where I can filter the data through categories